# Value pass from delegate method is nil Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, closures

I try to send data from one view controller (ItenaryVC) through delegate to another view controller (ItenaryFloatingPanelVC). The VC that initiates ItenaryVC is  DiscoverVC. When ItenaryVC load up it will make API calls to get some data, and I want to pass the data received from API calls to the delegate that I created which will pass the data to ItenaryFloatingPanelVC. But the data is not received and it is nil. I also actually using **FloatingPanel Library** to add the panel in ItenaryVC.

***Flow***

**DiscoverVC -> ItenaryVC + ItenaryFloatingPanelVC (as Flaoting Panel)**

**DiscoverVC.swift**

```
protocol DiscoverVCDelegate : AnyObject {
    func didSendSingleLocationData(_ discoverVC : DiscoverVC , location : Location)
}

class DiscoverVC : UIViewController {
    //MARK:- IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    weak var delegate : DiscoverVCDelegate?
    
    private var locationResult = [Location]()
    private var selectedAtRow : Int!
    
    //MARK:- Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        renderView()
        getLocations()
    }
    
    private func renderView() {
        
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: R.nib.discoverCell.name, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: R.reuseIdentifier.discoverCell.identifier)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    private func getLocations(location : String = "locations") {
        
        NetworkManager.shared.getLocations(for: location) {  [weak self] location in
            
            switch location {
            
            case .success(let locations):
                self?.updateDiscoverUI(with: locations)
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.rawValue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func updateDiscoverUI(with locations : [Location]) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.locationResult.append(contentsOf: locations)
            self?.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

//MARK:- Delegate
extension DiscoverVC : UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedAtRow = indexPath.row
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: R.segue.discoverVC.goToDetails, sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ItenaryVC else { return}
        
        destinationVC.locationDetails = locationResult[selectedAtRow]
        destinationVC.imageURL = locationResult[selectedAtRow].image
        destinationVC.getItenaries(at: locationResult[selectedAtRow].itenaryName)
        
        delegate?.didSendSingleLocationData(self, location: locationResult[selectedAtRow])
        // Remove tab bar when push to other vc
        destinationVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        
    }
}
```

**ItenaryVC.swift**

```
import UIKit
import FloatingPanel


protocol ItenaryVCDelegate : AnyObject {
    func didSendItenaryData(_ itenaryVC : ItenaryVC, with itenary : [[Days]])
}

class ItenaryVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

    var imageURL : URL!
    var locationDetails: Location! {
    didSet {
        getItenaries(at: locationDetails.itenaryName)
    }
}
    
    weak var delegate : ItenaryVCDelegate?
   
    var itenaries = [[Days]]()
   
    //MARK:- Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCard()
        setupView()
    }

    
    func getItenaries(at itenaries : String = "Melaka"){
        NetworkManager.shared.getItenaries(for: itenaries) { [weak self] itenary in
            switch itenary {
            
            case .success(let itenary):
               // print(itenary)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.itenaries.append(contentsOf: itenary)
                    self?.delegate?.didSendItenaryData(self! , with: itenary)
                }
               
                print(itenaries.count)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.rawValue)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

//MARK:- Private methods
extension ItenaryVC {
    
    private func setupView() {
        backgroundImage.downloaded(from: imageURL)
        backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    }
    
    private func setupCard() {
        guard let itenaryFlotingPanelVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "itenaryPanel") as? ItenaryFloatingPanelVC else { return}
        
        let fpc = FloatingPanelController()
        fpc.set(contentViewController: itenaryFlotingPanelVC)
        fpc.addPanel(toParent: self)

    }
}
```

**ItenaryFloatingPanelVC.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ItenaryFloatingPanelVC: UIViewController{
    
    
    //MARK:- Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var sloganLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locDesc: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var itenaryTableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var locDescHC: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    var itenaries = [[Days]]()
    
    
    let itenaryVC = ItenaryVC()
    let discoverVC = DiscoverVC()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        discoverVC.delegate = self
        itenaryVC.delegate = self
        
        itenaryTableView.dataSource = self
        itenaryTableView.delegate = self
    
        locDescHC.constant = locDesc.contentSize.height
        itenaryTableView.register(UINib(nibName: R.nib.itenaryCell.name, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: R.nib.itenaryCell.identifier)
    }
}



//MARK:- DiscoverVCDelegate
extension ItenaryFloatingPanelVC : DiscoverVCDelegate {
    func didSendSingleLocationData(_ discoverVC: DiscoverVC, location: Location) {
        print(location)
        locationLabel.text = location.locationName
    }
}

//MARK:- ItenaryVC Delegate
extension ItenaryFloatingPanelVC : ItenaryVCDelegate {
 
    func didSendItenaryData(_ itenaryVC: ItenaryVC, with itenary: [[Days]]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(itenary)
            self.itenaries.append(contentsOf: itenary)
            self.itenaryTableView.reloadData()
            print("itenary \(self.itenaries.count)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Image of ItenaryVC and ItenaryFloatingPanel**

[image]

Comment: Where is the code that presents `ItenaryVC`? I don't see anything in `ItenaryFloatingPanelVC` that does that (I might be blind). Or is `ItenaryVC` a container view controller?

Comment: actually, it has another VC that present the ItenaryVC, but the API request will be made when ItenaryVC initiate, ItenaryFloatingPanelVC s the panel that will be in ItenaryVC, just update the code ads your reference

Comment: In a storyboard environment `FloatingPanelController()` (and the other calls of the default initializer) will never return the instance you expect. You need the proper reference to the instance in the storyboard .

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean by proper reference?, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing now. So `ItenaryVC` presents `ItenaryFloatingPanelVC` and you are passing the data "forward"?

Comment: Yup correct, the data passed from ItenaryVC and DiscoverVC from closure of API calls to delegate to the ItenaryFloatingPanel

Comment: You need the reference by segue or instantiation from the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you have set the delegate of an newly created `ItenaryVC` instance:

```
let itenaryVC = ItenaryVC()

// ...

itenaryVC.delegate = self
```

`itenaryVC` here is not the VC that presented `self`, the `ItenaryFloatingPanelVC`. It's a brand new one that you created.

Instead of doing that, you can set the delegate in `ItenaryVC` when you are about to present `ItenaryFloatingPanelVC`:

```
private func setupCard() {
    guard let itenaryFlotingPanelVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "itenaryPanel") as? ItenaryFloatingPanelVC else { return }
    
    let fpc = FloatingPanelController()

    // here!
    self.delegate = itenaryFlotingPanelVC

    fpc.set(contentViewController: itenaryFlotingPanelVC)
    fpc.addPanel(toParent: self)
}
```

`self` is now the `ItenaryVC`, and `itenaryFlotingPanelVC` is the VC that `self` is presenting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you call `getItenaries()` in `ItenaryVC`. Please check again.

Comment: Yeah actually I already implement it before, just update the source code